# Is it a good/bad idea to use test features to strengthen learning parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am fairly new to machine learning and have started implementing a few classification algorithms.

From whatever I have read so far, **I understand that data is absolutely crucial for training the classifier model - more the data, better it is at generalizing.**

Now a classifier can predict correctly or wrongly. So what I  wish to know is this:

Is it a good idea to **use a new test feature set to modify the training parameters** every time the test feature set gets correctly classified (with the intention being to strengthen the model)?

What could be the problems if I tried this approach? **Would there be the presence of some sort of bias or preference in the classification?**

Also, am I treading upon the domain of ***reinforcement learning*** here?

Any thoughts upon this matter would be most appreciated...

Comment: By "new test feature set" are you referring to adding a new independent variable coded for each correct prediction?

Comment: @ArunJose Not exactly. Let's assume that the classification problem is to identify writers from their handwriting samples using a training model that has been trained using different features like stroke length, curvature etc. and that the model used is a simple naive bayes probability model. Say a new handwriting sample is provided to be tested i.e. to classify it as belonging to a particular writer and my model classifies it correctly. So now I wish to add this test sample into my training set and reevaluate all the training parameters (probabilities in this case).

Comment: If I understood your question, I'd say it depends on the goals of the analysis. I recommend you to look up "Semi-supervised learning".

Comment: @Firebug Thanks for the insight :) But would it not apply to any supervised learning situation? And yeah I am fairly sure what I am trying to achieve here is not really Reinforcement Learning. It is more inclined to semi-supervised learning (which I shall most certainly be delving into) like you mentioned or something like Online Learning (sort of)

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic of deep interest to me, but I have not achieved a strong enough grasp of statistics to explain its intuition mathematically. However, I can paraphrase a strategy for solving such problems.

While we discuss this topic, my only request would be to treat it as a guide for how one might choose to solve the problem, rather than figuring if your solution was the most comprehensive one possible. Data science is infinitely complex. It is futile to assume we would have a clue what the actual distribution is. Sample size governs all.

So if I'm faced with a business problem and the solution of which can gradually shift me towards a more optimal one then I have conceptually succeeded.

Now, long story short. In your case if your data gave you each day a new experiment that could help you answer one question - What is the best way I can predict what will happen tomorrow? This is in the most generic sense the objective of any data science.

So in effect, everything we ever will use statistics for is just this single truth. The moment a simple learning algorithm can somehow get better at just guessing on your behalf what happens tomorrow slightly better than you could with a calculator, you have shifted into an optimal mode of operation with autopilot. 
(This also has all sorts of oversight and operational issues of its own, but bear with me here.)

If in each subsequent day we perform a gradual  percentage on error lower we are better off. The longer we keep this journey, the more straight forward it is to see that eventually the models will evolve and possibly reduce the errors on most targets.

Now imagine this ability on steroids: if rather than trying to figure out what will happen next day, we can make slightly easier guesses about what will happen in the next 10 seconds, or 1 second for instance. Suddenly you can think of a massive number of things that we can easily learn without being too strict about the methodology.

If at the end of this path, for assume a week or two one of two things happen. Either you can see a clear evidence of change for better or you would find that the results aren't all the good. If it isn't good something is off. OR the system is inherently unpredictable in some way i.e. the stock market. Not "learnable".. yet, entirely.

I have no clue however if this answer actually addresses your question, but I've personally been able to see some actual change and often it didn't require much more complicated models than logistic regression, cluster analysis, linear regression. And you have neural networks to throw at at the drop of a hat for any big data problem you can think of. Be it genetic research or space exploration. You obviously have way more exciting discoveries to make than you have time for knowing one more type of probability distribution, for most human beings at least.

My two cents.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to share the learning you have gleaned from your own experience! It was a beautiful and sensible read :) And while it may not have been a direct answer to my question, there are some key takeaways for me here viz. (1) Give the solution a shot and observe how it performs (2) Occam's razor applies even to opaque fields like ML (3) Utility beats perfection as far as real world problems are concerned